# How do I fix a jittery/jumpy interface (specifically the refresh wheel) when loading data asynchronously in SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, xcode, asynchronous, firebase-realtime-database, swiftui

I've built an iPhone app to display train schedule and system alert data for the Washington DC Metro.

I have a Firebase Realtime Database in which I store data that I've pulled from WMATA's API, and my app loads data asynchronously and displays it for the user.

The app works properly, but sometimes the interface is a bit jittery, with the refresh wheel jumping quickly to the left before centering, and pages quickly flashing blank before data loads. I think this has something to do with the way I'm refreshing the interface before refreshing the actual data, which seems to be the "correct" way of doing things, but makes the app look more disjointed than I'd like. I'd probably be fine if I can figure out how to keep the refresh wheel from jumping around, but I'm also curious as to whether there's a good way of preventing UI elements from loading (in this case, the "All Tweets" link) until after the asynchronous data has loaded.

Here is the Alerts tab in my app, which shows the jumpy interface and quick flash of an uncentered "All Tweets" link before the page fully loads:

[image]

Here is my attempt at writing a simpler version of the code I'm using to display this page, which asynchronously loads alerts from Firebase as a task when the page loads.

```
import SwiftUI
import FirebaseDatabase


class AlertListDebug: ObservableObject {
    @Published var alerts = [String:[String:Any]]()

    //Initializers
    init() {
        
    }
            
    //Get data asynchronously
    @MainActor
    func getAlertsDataDebug(refAlertsRaw: DatabaseReference!, officialTwitter: String) async {
        self.alerts = [:]
        
        //Generate query
        var query: DatabaseQuery
        query = refAlertsRaw.child("alerts").child("raw_" + officialTwitter)
        
        //Query data
        query.observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { snapshot  in
            if(!(snapshot.value is NSNull)) {
                let dict = snapshot.value as! [String: Any]
                for element in dict {
                    let key = element.key
                    let alertRaw = element.value as! [String: Any]
                    let alert = ["lines": alertRaw["Line"]!, "text": alertRaw["Text"]!]
                    
                    //Add alert element to list
                    self.alerts[key] = alert
                }
            }
        }
        
    }
}


struct AlertsViewDebug: View {
    @StateObject var alertList = AlertListDebug()
    
    //Variable tracking whether official or Twitter alerts are being shown
    @State var officialTwitter = "official"
    
    //Create database reference
    var refAlertsRaw: DatabaseReference! = Database.database().reference()
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 0){
            //Official and Twitter alert source buttons
            HStack {
                Button(action: {
                    officialTwitter = "official";
                    Task {
                        await alertList.getAlertsDataDebug(refAlertsRaw: refAlertsRaw, officialTwitter: officialTwitter)
                    }
                }) {
                    Text("Official Alerts")
                }
                Spacer()
                Button(action: {
                    officialTwitter = "twitter";
                    Task {
                        await alertList.getAlertsDataDebug(refAlertsRaw: refAlertsRaw, officialTwitter: officialTwitter)
                    }
                }) {
                    Text("Twitter Feed")
                }
            }
            //Display list of alerts
            ScrollView {
                VStack(spacing: 0) {
                    if(alertList.alerts.count > 0) {
                        ForEach(alertList.alerts.keys.sorted(), id: \.self) {alertKey in

                            Text(alertKey)
                                .font(.system(size: 16))
                                .foregroundColor(.black)
                                .frame(width: 320)
                            
                        }
                    }
                }.overlay(
                    RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10)
                        .stroke(.black, lineWidth: 1)
                )
                .padding(.vertical, 5)
                if(officialTwitter == "twitter") {
                    //Browser link to Twitter feed
                    Text("All Tweets")
                }
            }.task {
                await alertList.getAlertsDataDebug(refAlertsRaw: refAlertsRaw, officialTwitter: officialTwitter)
            }.refreshable {
                await alertList.getAlertsDataDebug(refAlertsRaw: refAlertsRaw, officialTwitter: officialTwitter)
            }
            Spacer()
        }.navigationTitle("Alerts")
        .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
    }
}
```

Please let me know if I'm going about this incorrectly - thank you!

Comment: Hi Jack, and welcome to Stack Overflow. Please update your code to show a minimal example that reproduces the issue; ideally a `struct ContentView` that someone can paste into Xcode and run. As it stands you have objects such as `OfficialTwitterButton` and `AlertCardView`  that probably have nothing to do with the problem you want us to solve. Please take a look at [mcve]

Comment: Thank you! I went ahead and updated the code to only include the basics, but I don't think anyone can just paste it into Xcode and run it, since it relies on a Firebase database with authentication info in my `GoogleService-Info.plist` file. However, when I run this as a preview in my Xcode project, I still get the jumpy refresh wheel, so I know this reproduces the bug. Is this good enough, or do you need me to make some more changes before you can take a look?

Comment: The problem probably doesn't lie with Firebase itself, so you could add some dummy async functions that simulate what's happening. At the very least, if you're still seeing there issue, that would rule Firebase out as the cause.